# Sound is very flaky on Dell Inspiron running 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell, headphones

My Dell Inspiron 3501 is using the Cirrus Logic 8409 sound card.  I did a fresh install of Kubuntu 21.10, and sound is very flaky.  There does not seem to be a rhyme or reason when it works or not.  Sometimes when i reboot, the sound comes back.  Sometimes i need to plugin headphones and then unplug them (but that only works on the rare occasion the headphones are detected).  Sometimes it stops working out of the blue.  I am sure there is a reason, i just have not found a pattern yet.  I tried all the recommendations, like "alsa force-reload", going into "alsamixer" and make sure everything is setup properly, but to no avail.

Has anybody had the same issue and resolved it?  Or is more information needed?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a DELL with Ubuntu 20.04 and had the problem that sound was not working at all.
The solutions on the Internet all point to run `sudo alsa force-reload` (after each start up) or running `systemctl disable timidity`

Does something like that work for you?